# Star-autonomous categories are categorifications of Boolean algebras?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, boolean-algebras, categorification

I asked this question fourteen days ago on MathStackexchange (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460652/star-autonomous-categories-are-categorifications-of-boolean-algebras)). I have not received any answers or comments until now. It seems to me that on MathStackexchange not many people are familiar with star-autonomous categories. Following [Nick Champion's advice](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5012/can-i-ask-a-question-on-mathoverflow-and-also-on-another-site/5013#5013), I therefore have decided to cross-post the question on this site.

**1. Question**
The [n-Lab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chu+construction) on the Chu-construction says:

> "Armed with just this much knowledge, and knowledge of how star-autonomous categories behave (as **categorified versions of Boolean algebras**, or perhaps better Boolean rigs), the star-autonomous structure on $\operatorname{Chu}(C,d)$ can pretty much be deduced (or strongly guessed) […]."

How do star-autonomous categories behave as categorified versions of Boolean algebras or Boolean rigs? In what way is the term categorification used here?

**2. Wikipedia says**
One explanation might be given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-autonomous_category#Examples):

> "A degenerate example [of a star-autonomous category] (all homsets of cardinality at most one) is given by any Boolean algebra (as a partially ordered set) made monoidal using conjunction for the tensor product and taking 0 as the dualizing object."

I suppose the internal hom of two objects $a,b$ in this category is $\neg a \lor b $, correct? The dual functor is the complement?

Edit for future readers: The quoted statement on the nLab seems to have been inaccurate. The nLab entry has now been changed to: "Armed with just this much knowledge, and knowledge of how star-autonomous categories behave (*as categorified versions of linear logic*), the star-autonomous structure on $\operatorname{Chu}(C,d)$ can pretty much be deduced (or strongly guessed).“

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting point for decategorification is the observation that a category in which any parallel arrows are equal must necessarily be a preorder.
Restricting to skeletal categories makes it a poset.

Thus, we might as well ask: what is a *-autonomous category whose underlying category is a poset?

For the specific case when the poset is a Boolean algebra,
we set $A→B=A⊸B$, and $A⊢B$ means there is a morphism $A→B$.
We have $A⊗X≅(A⊸X^*)^*$, which means $A⊗X=A∧B$.
Most axioms of propositional logic are now straightforward to verify.
In particular, we can identify the global dualizing object $⊥$:
if for all objects $A$ the canonical map $A→(A⊸⊥)⊸⊥$
is an isomorphism, then $⊥$ must be the initial object,
since $B⊢(A→B)$ in our case.

More generally, *-autonomous posets that are not Boolean algebras provide models for [linear logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear%20logic).  So in the strict sense *-autonomous categories do not categorify Boolean algebras (or rigs), but rather the corresponding algebraic structure for linear logic.

Comment: Well, any compact closed category is star-autonomous. So you seem to argue that Boolean algebras are categorifications of compact closed categories rather than star-autonomous categories.

Comment: @M.C.: It is not me who is arguing this, it is the original poster, who mentioned Boolean rigs vs Boolean algebras in this context.

Comment: Right, but then I find their statement rather inaccurate. Thank you for the explanation by the way.

Comment: If I think of dualization as the categorical analog of negation, then the isomorphism $(A\otimes B)^*\cong A^*\otimes B^*$ (for compact closed categories) seems to be the analog of $\neg(A\land B)\equiv (\neg A)\land(\neg B)$, which holds in no nontrivial Boolean algebras.

Comment: The recent edit renders moot the opening three comments. I will probably delete these comments in a while.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "in our case" in the last sentence.  It certainly isn't true that there is always a morphism from $B$ to $A\multimap B$ in any $*$-autonomous category, even if it is a poset.  Nor is it true that the dualizing object must be initial.  In general, star-autonomous posets are the proof-irrelevant semantics of classical (multiplicative) *linear* logic, which is more general than classical logic that corresponds to Boolean algebras.

Comment: @MikeShulman: Thanks, so the nLab claim is actually not true.  I edited it accordingly.